# Don't write text into my txt file

Tags: java, readfile, writefile

With this code I want to read one text file, put all elements into a arraylist and replace the file with the the arraylist contain. But this code don't write into file and I don't know why...

```
public void delete(String lineToDelete, String nameFile) throws IOException {
        file = new File(nameFile);
        fw = new FileWriter(file,false);

        read = new Scanner(file);
        while (read.hasNext()) {
            itemFile.add(read.nextLine());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < itemFile.size(); i++) {
            if (itemFile.get(i).equals(lineToDelete)) {
                itemFile.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        for (String itemFile1 : itemFile) {
            fw.write(itemFile1);
            fw.write(System.lineSeparator()); //new line
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it throw any errors? Have you tried to step through your code, either with a debugger or by print statements?

Comment: Nop... I don't have any errors..

Comment: Redundant java tags are unnecessary. What about this code requires a specific version?

Comment: Try closing/flushing your streams/writers.

Comment: the itemfile is a arraylist where I put all my file, and after that i try to put the contain in the same text file

Comment: because you use 'fwp' instead of 'fw'

Comment: press a wrong key here, in my code are fw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your scanner before opening your FileWriter, to avoid conflicts on the file.

```
    ...
    read.close();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,false);
    for (String itemFile1 : itemFile) {
        fw.write(itemFile1);
        fw.write(System.lineSeparator()); //new line
    }
    fw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe theres a typo. In the last for loop you have fwp.write(...) when your variable's name is fw. This could be the problem.